# IntelliJ automatically created Android JUnit run configurations for JUnit tests

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

When I generate tests in IntelliJ via *CTRL+SHIFT+T* and try and run those tests, the temporary run configuration created is in the `Android JUnit` category. Can I change this to be `JUnit`?

Comment: Do you have Android modules in project? What IDE version do you use?

Comment: 2018.1.5 and I have Android modules in my project, however the tests are in a non-Android core module. I'm hoping this is just a config thing I can change somewhere. I know my IDE version is pretty old, but I've had issues migrating versions with this specific project before, so I've just left it because it works :)

Comment: Could you please try to install newer version in parallel and check if the same issue occurs with sample project? AFAIK it should be fixed in newer releases.